# Use of Power Set in showing that the generic extension satisfies Replacement

Tags: set-theory, forcing

My question essentially boils down to the following:

> Given a countable transitive model (henceforth ctm) $M$ of ZFC-P (where P denotes the Power Set Axiom), $\mathbb{P}$ a forcing notion in $M$, and $G$ an $M$-generic filter, can we conclude that $M[G]\models$ ZFC-P?

Looking at Kunen's treatment of forcing, both the Truth and the Definability Lemmas are stated for ctm of ZF-P. However, when reading through the proof that the generic extension satisfies ZF-P, there is an appeal to the Reflection Theorem (within $M$) to show that each instance of Replacement holds in $M[G]$:

[image]

A similar thing happens in Schindler's *Set Theory*, where he uses Scott's Trick to cut down a collection of names to a set in $M$, thereby relying on Power Set. Can this be circumvented? I'm not sure whether this happens in the Boolean valued approach, but I would wager that constructing completions for arbitrary posets might be tricky without Power Set.

It would be nice if this was doable, because one can produce, in ZFC, countable transitive models of ZFC-P + "for every $x$, $[x]^{\aleph_0}$ exists", so then we could get actual set models of the full ZFC-P + "for every $x$, $[x]^{\aleph_0}$ exists" + ¬CH, via the usual forcing argument. In fact, the following is stated in Kanovei's *Borel Equivalence Relations*, lemma A.3.1:

> If $\mathfrak{M}$ is a countable transitive model of ZFC - P + "for every $x$, $[x]^{\aleph_0}$ exists", $P$ is countable in $\mathfrak{M}$ and $G$ is $P$-generic over $\mathfrak{M}$, then $\mathfrak{M}[G]$ is still a model of ZFC-P+"for every $x$, $[x]^{\aleph_0}$ exists".

EDIT:

Something I thought of while working on completely unrelated stuff: If we have that the ground model $M$ satisfies Collection, instead of Replacement, then Kunen's proof goes through, without any appeal to the Reflection Theorem. So, if Collection holds in the ground model, then it holds in the extension. But producing ctm of ZFC-P with Collection instead of Replacement is easy, since $H_\kappa$ models this theory for regular uncountable $\kappa$.

Is the last paragraph correct? I don't immediately see a flaw.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding when you write "he uses Scott's Trick ... thereby relying on Power Set" (I haven't read his argument), but I don't believe Scott's trick relies on powerset, just foundation.  The existence of a rank function follows from well-foundedness.  Although you would use powerset to characterize rank in terms of the $V_\alpha$s, it's not necessary for a rank function.

Comment: @JunderscoreH Don’t you need Power Set to assert that $V_\alpha$ is a set, and not a proper class? I was under the impression that the fact that each $V_\alpha$ is a set is what makes Scott’s trick work

Comment: Ah yes, that's very true: collection is strictly stronger than replacement in the absence of powerset. My mistake!

Comment: I think your $Q$ is obtainable by applying the axiom of collection instead. Of course, collection is stronger than replacement but it is weaker than reflection theorem.

Comment: @HanulJeon How do we get collection in the ground model, given that we only have replacement there?

Comment: Oops, sorry. This seems not possible.

Comment: It's common to add collection instead of replacement when removing powerset, if $\mathsf{ZF}^-$ denotes the theory $\mathsf{ZF}$ without powerset and with collection instead of replacement then (set) forcing over a ground model of $\mathsf{ZF}^-$ will preserve $\mathsf{ZF}^-$, but I'm not sure whether adding $AC$ to the ground model is enough to get $AC$ in the forcing extension. However since you only seem to be removing powerset from $\mathsf{ZF}$ I don't think that this will be preserved in every forcing extension

Comment: Actually which version of which book by Kunen are you looking at? In "Set Theory", revised 2013 edition, Lemma IV.2.26 explicitely states that if $M$ models $ZF-P$, then $M[G]$ models all axioms of $ZF-P$ except possibly replacement, while the next lemma says that if you have $ZF(C)$ in the ground model you get $ZF(C)$ in the forcing extension

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Thank you for your comments. So, with how things are stated in Kunen (and yes, I'm looking at the 2013 version), it would points to Power Set indeed being indeed necessary.

Comment: @Reveillark yes, it looks like it's necessary. Unfortunately I don't have an example of a forcing over a model $M$ of $ZF-P$ such that $M[G]\nvDash$replacement, but if anyone comes up with one I think it'd be a good answer for your question